# WSO2 - Enterprise Integrator - Filter Mediator

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I am trying to understand how Filter Mediator works.
I have a Proxy service that talks to a SOAP API.  I tried to introduce Filter Mediator to it for header based routing but it is not working anymore.

Please see and let me know what I have done wrong here.

```
soapProxy.xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <proxy name="soapProxy" startOnLoad="true" transports="http https" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
        <target>
            <inSequence>
                <filter regex="test" source="get-property('transport','header1')">
                    <then>
                        <log description="ifLog" level="custom">
                            <property name="value" value="---------- Then Clause ---"/>
                        </log>
                        <send>
                            <endpoint key="SoapEndpoint"/>
                        </send>
                    </then>
                    <else>
                        <log description="elseLog" level="custom">
                            <property name="value" value="--- Else Clause ---"/>
                        </log>
                        <log description="log1" level="custom" separator="&#xa; --->  ">
                            <property name="log1.message" value=" ---> printing log1"/>
                            <property expression="get-property('transport','header1')" name="log1.headerProperty"/>
                        </log>
                        <property description="welcomeMsgProperty" name="welcomeMsg" scope="default" type="STRING" value="------ Hello World Property Mediator"/>
                        <log description="log2" separator="&#xa; --->  ">
                            <property name="log2.message" value="  -------------> Welcome to Log Mediator"/>
                            <property expression="get-property(&quot;log2.message&quot;)" name="log2.MyProperty"/>
                            <property expression="get-property(&quot;MessageID&quot;)" name="log2.msgID"/>
                            <property expression="get-property(&quot;welcomeMsg&quot;)" name="log2.welcomeMsg"/>
                            <property expression="$trp:Content-Type" name="log2.stockprop"/>
                        </log>
                        <send>
                            <endpoint key="SoapEndpoint"/>
                        </send>
                    </else>
                </filter>
            </inSequence>
            <outSequence>
                <log description="resLog" separator="&#xa; --->  ">
                    <property expression="get-property(&quot;welcomeMsg&quot;)" name="welcomeMsg"/>
                    <property name="test" value="*****"/>
                </log>
                <send/>
            </outSequence>
            <faultSequence/>
        </target>
    </proxy>


 **SoapEndpoint.xml**
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <endpoint name="SoapEndpoint" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
        <address format="soap12" optimize="swa" uri="http://localhostlocal:9090/ws/countries.wsdl"/>
        <property name="ENDPOINT_ADDRESS" value="http://localhost.local:9090/ws/countries.wsdl"/>
    </endpoint>
```

**I then tried using sequence Mediator to redirect requests but am getting erroe there too.** 
ERROR - SequenceMediator Sequence named Value {name ='null', keyValue ='sequence1'} cannot be found

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="sequence1" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <send>
        <endpoint>
            <address uri="http://localhost:9090/ws/countries.wsdl"/>
        </endpoint>
    </send>
</sequence>


<filter regex="test" source="get-property('transport','header1')">
                <then>
                    <log description="ifLog" level="custom">
                        <property name="value" value="---------- Then Clause ---"/>
                    </log>
                    <sequence key="sequence1"/>
                </then>
.....
.....
```

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask an actual question (as opposed to listing tags). Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The following proxy is working for me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="soapProxy" startOnLoad="true" statistics="disable" trace="disable" transports="http,https">
<target>
    <inSequence>
        <filter regex="test" source="get-property('transport','header1')">
            <then>
                <log level="custom">
                    <property name="value" value="---------- Then Clause ---"/>
                </log>
                <send>
                    <endpoint>
                        <http uri-template="http://www.mocky.io/v2/5185415ba171ea3a00704eed"/>
                    </endpoint>
                </send>
            </then>
            <else>
                <log level="custom">
                    <property name="value" value="--- Else Clause ---"/>
                </log>
                <send>
                    <endpoint>
                        <http uri-template="http://www.mocky.io/v2/5185415ba171ea3a00704eed"/>
                    </endpoint>
                </send>
            </else>
        </filter>
        <respond/>
    </inSequence>
</target>
<description/>
```

use following CURL commands.

curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:8280/services/soapProxy \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -H 'header1: test2' \
  -H 'postman-token: d4d1e767-3cd7-39a6-2782-58ab0ffba987' \
  -d '
{
  "a" : "a"
}'

curl -X POST \
  http://localhost:8280/services/soapProxy \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'content-type: application/json' \
  -H 'header1: test' \
  -H 'postman-token: d4d1e767-3cd7-39a6-2782-58ab0ffba987' \
  -d '
{
  "a" : "a"
}'